# using gawk in batch windows

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, gawk

I am trying to use a simple gawk command from a batch file in windows. gawk.exe is accessed throughout cygwin. This is the command:

```
gawk '{if ( $1 GTR 1197 ) {print ($0) }  else {} }' %input% > %output%
```

What I want to do is the following: if the first column of input file is bigger thatn 1197 value, then all the row is printed. input file has the following format:

```
16.0   23    40
17.0    4   -40
17.0   23    -4
18.0    4     8
```

Due to an unknown reason, my output is equal to the input, so the if statement is not being recognized.

Comment: `GTR` ??? what's that? Does gawk support comparisons like that, rather than `<=`, etc? Good luck.

Comment: '>' symbol is not being recognized, that is the reason why I tried with GTR (some webs talk about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the problem, it was due to the special character. Introducing before the greater command the symbol ^ (as an scape character, more info [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)) it works:

```
gawk ' $1 ^> 1197 { print } ' %input% > %output%
```

Thanks for the answers. Hope this can help other people with the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

The code for `gawk` is:

```
 gawk "$1 > 1197" "%input%" > "%output%"
```

example:

```
>type file
16.0    23      40
17.0    4       -40
17.0    23      -4
18.0    4       8
2000    6       9
1197    2       1
>gawk "$1 > 1197" file
2000    6       9
```

Quoting is for [gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm). On Cygwin you should use single quotes: `gawk '$1 > 1197'`.

Comment: I have tried your advice, but it is not accepting the greater command. It only works with equal command. I have tried GTR too but it is still not working. I have read in some webs that also some people have problems with greater commands. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: No, the command works fine here. I never heard here at SO about issues with `>` in awk. I use gawk for Windows.